# How to enable autocomplete for the first time in Emacs for a beginner?

Tags: java, c++, c, emacs, editor

I am a beginner to programming, I know Java as well as C, but how do I enable autocomplete in Emacs when I start it for the first time. I have tried googing lots and still can't come up with a solution because of its complexity.

Please kindly help me with step by step solution.So if I am typing code, it should complete it for me.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095715/emacs-auto-complete-mode-at-startup) help at all?

Comment: @user2282137 he wants to know if the answers to that question are what you are looking for.

Comment: @chris Thank you, I did not see the link to this to be honest, sorry my bad, I looked at it already!

Answer (score 4):

You could try Java auto complete: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoJavaComplete

Comment: @user2282137: no sorry, I don't

Answer (score 2):

There a few autocomplete extensions available on the emacs wiki:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete

If you follow the links there, you can find manuals on how to go about installing/using autocomplete in emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Look to following [article about CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) - it also contains instructions on how to use it with autocomplete.